# Emulating tape distortion of low-level audio signals

Tags: audio, audio-processing, amplitude, distortion

I'm working on a tape echo emulation in Reaktor, and I've based the frequency response, tape speed warble, high-amplitude saturation and tape hiss on a paper I found about the Roland Space Echo. However, I'm now looking for information about the distortion of low-amplitude signals by audio tape. When I let an echo trail die out to just above the tape hiss level, and then turn up the feedback level to make it audible again, the sound is too clean, whereas a real tape delay would produce a heavily distorted sound.

**Which simple curve or mathematical transformation of a signal would emulate the distortion caused by recording audio on tape at very low levels?** And how should I adapt it to emulate different tape speeds?

It doesn't have to be very realistic or high quality, just something that will add some tape-like dirt to low-level signals only, and be mostly transparent at higher levels.

Comment: Please suggest better tags or migration to another site if necessary.

Comment: Maybe you can try a stateless non-linearity that clips out the low amplitude similar to class B amplifier distortion. something like $y(x) = sign(x) \cdot max(x-x_{bias},0)$ . If you want it to work over a wider dynamic range you could make $x_{bias}$ a function of the RMS of the input but cap it at whatever you consider to be "low level".

Comment: @Hilmar Ah, I think I've actually used that before in a Reaktor synth; didn't know about the class B amp link. Any idea whether that would be similar to what tape distortion at low levels sounds like?

Comment: No idea. I haven't worked with tape for a VERY long time.